# Input Multiple Word String with Other Input Types in a Single Line

Tags: c++, input

So suppose I want to give a line of input, for example:

12345 My name is Foo

i want to store 12345 into an int and "My name is Foo" into a string. I know there is a function std::getline, but that includes the whole line. Also, "My name is Foo" includes spaces, so it is not as simple. So how would I go about doing this? Thanks, I'm new to C++.

```
int i;
std::string s;

std::cin >> ...
```

So if I input:

12345 My name is Foo

then i = 12345 and s = "My name is Foo"

Comment: Do `std::cin >> i;` to get the number and then `std::getline(std::cin, s);` to get the rest.

Comment: @DimChtz Still need to skip white space after the reading the number though, with e.g. `std::istream::sentry`

Comment: @CruzJean Yes, I still need to skip those spaces. Is there a way to skip them without the code you wrote?

Comment: Just remove the whitespace: `s = s.substr(1);`

Comment: @DimChtz But that assumes there's exactly one space (might not even be white space). I'd put [`std::istream::sentry sentry(std::cin);`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/sentry) after reading the number but before reading the rest of the line.

Comment: what if you add another integer after as well, so the input becomes
12345 My name is Foo 54321
and you want i1 = 12345, and i2 = 54321

Answer (score 0):

You can use both `std::cin` and `std::getline()` and as @CruzJean suggested use `std::istream::sentry` to ignore whitespaces:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {

    std::string name;
    int n;

    std::cin >> n;
    std::istream::sentry sentry(std::cin);
    std::getline(std::cin, name);

    std::cout << name << "\n";
    std::cout << n << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```